# Seeking single word denoting a word pair in which one cannot exist without the other

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Years ago a friend told me about word pairs in which one word cannot exist without the other word. The example he used was *inside* and *outside*. That is, *inside* cannot exist without its necessary other half *outside*.

At the time he told me a name for these word pairs, which I have long forgotten. What is the name describing these word pairs?

Comment: Lots of words exist without their corresponding opposite. Consider _portable_: easily moved or carried. It doesn't have a ready, common antonym. There is no rule that a word needs to have an opposite to exist. A language could easily have "inside" and "not inside".

Comment: OK, @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇, point taken. I guess there are a lot of names that are without an opposite. You could say that the opposite of +2 is -2.

Comment: Lacunas do exist:  as  Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 says, '... words exist without their corresponding opposite', even when there is a case to be made for there being such opposites.

Comment: Does this include for example *prose* (which cannot exist without the concept *poetry*)?

Comment: I'm confused by @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇's comment and its upvotes - nowhere do I see the question assuming that **all** words come in pairs.

Comment: @alok there are _no_ words which cannot exist without an antonym. It's a false premise.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Why do you say that?

Comment: @vladkornea words exist because we create them. Concepts can exist independently of the labels we assign them. You don't need the word "outside" to create the word "inside". Otherwise how would you even create "outside" to go with "inside"? "Prose" exists whether or not we have poetry. The label for it is only useful if we have done reason to distinguish prose from non-prose, but we don't need the word "poetry" for that.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 We need the concept "poetry" in order to have the concept "prose". Therefore if we have the word "prose", there is no way that we don't also have the word "poetry". You can't define "prose" as merely "not something". That something (poetry) has to be named.

Comment: @vladkornea we don't need the word "poetry" to have poetry and thus the concept of prose. I already gave an example of a word whose opposite has no word. We don't have single words for all concepts and we don't have words for the "opposite" of all concepts. Why would we? What's the word for things that aren't portable?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Please define "prose" without reference to poetry.

Comment: [prose](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Aprose): written or spoken language in its ordinary form, without metrical structure.

Comment: Thing is, if you can't define "prose" without a reference to "poetry", and can't define "poetry" without a reference to "prose", then neither word can ever exist at all. One of them *has* to come first.

Comment: So is this question literally asking about a "word pair" or a "concept pair"?

Answer (score 4):

Consider *[complement](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=complement)*

> Either of two parts that complete the whole or mutually complete each other.

Similarly, *[counterpart](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=counterpart)*

> One of two parts that fit and complete each other.

both from *American Heritage*

Comment: adj. *complementary* used in Geometry to describe adjacent angles on a line.

Answer (score 1):

Having two opposing concepts that are defined by each other is an example of yin yang **[duality](http://personaltao.com/teachings/questions/what-is-yin-yang/)** which may be the word you're looking for.

Other than than, two words with opposite meanings are also **antonyms** or **complementary** to each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ***binary opposition***.

> A binary opposition (also binary system) is a pair of related terms or concepts that are opposite in meaning. Binary opposition is the system by which, in language and thought, two theoretical opposites are strictly defined and set off against one another. **It is the contrast between two mutually exclusive terms, such as on and off, up and down, left and right.** [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_opposition)

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

---

***Deconstruction*** theory touches upon binary oppositions and explains how one of them cannot exist without the other:

> Deconstruction is interested in the hierarchic binaries set up within texts. These could be: man/woman, speech/writing, white/black, inside/outside, full/empty, identity/difference, light/dark, presence/absence, similarity/difference. In each of these binaries, one term is privileged over the other. **A deconstructive reading would show how, even when a text appears to privilege one term over the other (say, inside over outside), the text's logic of rhetoric reveals that there can be no inside without the outside.** In other words, deconstruction shows how the less privileged term is central to the dominant term. By showing this centrality deconstruction reverses the hierarchy, for if the inside can exist only if there is an outside it means that the outside is the dominant element.
>
> In its next stage, deconstruction destabilizes this reverse hierarchy too. It questions the new hierarchy and thus leaves even the displaced one unstable. Thus, the text remains unresolvable where neither term is privileged - a situation called 'aporia'.
>
> <sub>*Contemporary Literary And Cultural Theory: From Structuralism To Ecocriticism*
> by Nayar</sub>

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, this nonsense argument cannot explain why in some pairs of words in which one is clearly "privileged," the "hierarchy" remains "stable."  *Ruthless* and *ruthful*, for example.  The former is a common usage, and relies not on the existence of the latter, an archaic word most people are unaware of.  Also, unfortunately, there are no operational definitions of "privileged," "centrality," "destabilizing," or "existence."

Comment: You didn't read it all. Sometimes none of them is privileged. Though it is more of a philosophical theory but influences the langugage. The actual answer is binary opposition.

Comment: I read it all.  I think you mean that sometimes neither of them is privileged, but so what?  That's not the case with my example.  I have no objection to the term "binary opposition," just to the baggage that comes with it.  In mathematics binary opposites (e.g., interior, exterior) are not mutually defined, so I doubt the fundamental philosophical insight.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Collocation, but those don't have to be together, they are just usually found going together when used in context.

Answer (score 0):

Dichotomy is a good word.  It implies a relationship to opposites or at least contrasting ideas. I'm Not sure if its what your looking for. Though, I do feel the question is rather vague.

Comment: As a first-time user, I appreciate the great contributions and discussions! As OP, the phrase "binary opposition" best fits my memory of my friends insight..The other offerings make for excellent 'ponderables' (yes, I made it up) and I appreciate all.

Answer (score 0):

**Inseparable** gives more emphasis on the fact that something cannot exist alone.

Something can also be **dependent upon** something else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of [antonym](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antonym)? (dictionary.reference.com)

> a word opposite in meaning to another. Fast is an antonym of slow.